# Facing issue in parsing a tag in xml through pl/sql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am looking to find a way to get a tag value through simple extract() or extractvalue() command, however I am unable to do so.

```
create table foo(
    xml_response XMLTYPE
 );

 insert into foo values('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-     ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns0:CSXWEBSVResponse xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/TransatorWebService">
  <ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out>Some     Text</ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out>
</ns0:CSXWEBSVResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
```

I need value of tag ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out, i.e. output is 'Some text'

```
 SELECT extract(xml_response,'SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-    ENV:Body/ns0:CSXWEBSVResponse/ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out/text()').getstringval() "REFERENCE" FROM foo

 ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
 ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
 LPX-00601: Invalid token in: 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-    ENV:Body/ns0:CSXWEBSVResponse/ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_Waout/text()'
```

I went through similar question/answers but non of them could help me fully. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the namespace in the EXTRACT function. Try this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(xml_response,'//ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out/text()','xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/TransatorWebService"').getStringVal() 
FROM foo
```

NOTE: I needed to change a little bit the XML you provided:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  xml_response XMLTYPE
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns0:CSXWEBSVResponse xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/TransatorWebService">
  <ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out>Some     Text</ns0:TransatorWebServiceContent_out>
</ns0:CSXWEBSVResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
```