# Exception ORA-31011: XML parsing failed

Tags: oracle, soap

I am calling a SOAP based webservice using PL/SQL block. The response returned is in the following format:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header/>
<env:Body>
  <ns0:getDocumentDataResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/ScheduleReportService">
     <ns3:getDocumentData   ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/ScheduleReportService">JVBERi0xLjYNCjUgMCB       vYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvWE9iamVjdA0KL1N1YnR5cGUgL0ltYWdlDQov
RmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQ0KL0xlbmd0aCA1MzUNCi9XaWR0aCA5Mg0KL0hlaWdodCAxNQ0K
L0JpdHNQZXJDb21wb25lbnQgOA0KL0NvbG9yU3BhY2UgL0RldmljZVJHQg0KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0K
eJztVzuOAjEM5U65yJwip6DgGnOhrai5AhLNLh0SRfZ5nDiexPFktS1PFgqMYz//kiGlD47xeDzS
9WoKPdJ4/4w0s/g40nm9Xo5xeUqLGbhsszWT5LKkU0inky0hpBjrXixGmqI/ivp8yTqmAvivK20f
 WT5fqECOBYXn80nuHGvwxe4aU/hRx2JKE6nkxNfvOetkhkCcFahkVJqxZTx9/9CuiZxQ6jTzXmLM
 ....
 OWExMDllPjxhMWE2NTE2ZDNmYTcwY2Y2NzhkY2EwMWIzZjlhMTA5ZT5dDQo+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVm
 DQoxMDg0MTIwDQolJUVPRg0K</ns3:getDocumentData>
      </ns0:getDocumentDataResponse>
      </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

This response is stored in the variable : l_xml_response_text(varchar2) and when I execute the following code:

```
l_xml_response_xmltype := xmltype(l_xml_response_text);
```

it Is throwing the error:

> Exception ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
>
> ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
>
> LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered

Is the issue due to data returned in decoded format? If yes..how can this be handled?

Comment: Your SOAP response is either not well-formed, or you need to try a different approach.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812807/facing-issue-in-parsing-a-tag-in-xml-through-pl-sql

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen- I have verified that it is a well formed XML also my requirement is to extract the value of getDocumentData tag and for that I am using the xmltype function with the XMLtable function.

Comment: Please show us your PL/SQL code. Perhaps you missed something around `UTL_HTTP.read_text()`.

Comment: Are you sure the document is well-formed? For example `<ns3:getDocumentData   ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/ScheduleReportService">` is not well-formed XML. What do you see when you do `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_xml_response_text);`

Comment: On further analysis, I was able to see that DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_xml_response_text) is printing only a part of the data (since the amount of data is  huge). Is it possible that, since it is not fetching the whole data.. it is not able to extract the ending tags for the XML and thus giving this error?

Comment: Yes, I have the same error `LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered` for this exaple 

`SELECT XMLTYPE('<a><b>test</b></a') FROM dual`